# AWK command failing for large file

Tags: awk

I have a `.csv` file of 6.5 GB. I need to sort the files with 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 13th column and need to get the unique records. Also I need to get the duplicate records and redirect it to some other file.

I am using the following command to get the unique lines:

```
awk -F',' 'a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$13]++' /var/tmp/Data.txt > unique.txt
```

But the above process is consuming more than 3.5 GB memory and eventually gets terminated. Producing the following error in the log file:

```
sh: line 1:  7895 Killed                  awk -F',' 'a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$13]++' /var/tmp/Data.txt > unique.txt
```

How can I produce the required output?

Comment: In general I would not recommend parsing `.csv` files with regular expressions. Some files have quoted values, and sometimes span multiple lines. Some implementations of Excel produce semi-colon separated values. IMHO you better use Python/Perl/Ruby and a real CSV parsing library, that will save you time.

Comment: What operating system and version are you using? Why are you surprised about the memory usage — each line creates a new entry in a table and it adds up. You mention sorting, are you doing this on a sorted file?

Comment: Why don't you use sort? Reorder the fields using awk (move field 13 to position 6), then sort -k 1,6.

Answer (score 2):

For each line where the specified fields are not unique, you store some data in memory that contains the specified field plus a small overhead. So unless you have a lot of duplicates or the other fields are very large, it's unsurprising that a 6.5GB file would cause more than 3.5GB to be used.

If the file is already sorted, you don't need to store all that data, only to compare adjacent lines.

```
awk -F ',' '
    {current = $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$13}
    previous == current {print}
    {previous = current}
'
```

or

```
sed -n -e 'x' -e 'G' -e '/^\(.*)\n\1$/ { s/\n.*//; p; }' \
```

If the file isn't sorted, sorting is likely to be the fastest way of getting the information. Typical `sort` implementations are good with very large files.

Answer (score 0):

Try : Did you missed `!` before `a` ?

```
  $ awk -F',' '!a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$13]++' < /var/tmp/Data.txt > unique.txt
```

If your `OS` or any commands you use to parse it is not 64 bits nor compiled or designed to support such kind of architecture, you will surely have some problem to handle a 6.5Gb files (process won't be able to adress the required memory).
if 32bit : 2^32 which is around 4Gb will be the limit.(could be even less with signed interger for example limit will be 2Gb)
`man largefile` [Man largefile](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?largefile+5) may also give you some clue.